# Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions

Tags: magento

I’m trying to set-up Magento on my server, but I still haven’t succeeded in installing plugins. When I go to the /downloader/ folder, I get the message:

> Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions. 
>   If you wish to proceed downloading Magento packages online, please set all Magento folders to have writable permission for the web server user (example: apache) or set up FTP Connection on the Magento Connect Manager Settings tab.
>   ```

I have recursively changed the permissions of all the files and folders via FTP and set them to 777, but that didn’t work. Then I asked my webhoster to chmod everything as well, but still it throws the same error. When I look at the project in FTP, I see that all files and folders are correctly set-up to 777.

Why do I still get this message and what can I do?

In this particular case I’m trying to install the `LightSpeed eCommerce Connector` (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lightspeed-ecommerce-connector.html). Is there some other way I can install this plugin without the Magento connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, figured it out. The webroot itself must also have write permissions. I don't know why and frankly I find that ridiculous, but it's working.

Comment: Hi, I am having same problem with my magento, how to set the webroot itself to have write permission? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the httpdocs or public_html folder in your webserver,
while logged in via SSH, try this:

```
   chown -R apache:apache ./*
   find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 '{}' ';'
   find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 '{}' ';'
   chown apache:apache ./
   chmod 755 ./
```

Answer (score 0):

We also need to provide sufficient permission to the var and media folder to make the site works correctly.

Below are the permission commands we can use to run Magento and provide permission through SSH.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```